# pass a value into next page

Tags: asp.net

I have login page, once logged in I create a session variable to store the UserName.
I've used this variable to retrieve info for this User from Account table with AccountID, name etc and I return the AccountID on the page using a label (lblAccountID).

I have a button to "Add Funds" to this account, which redirects to the AddFunds.aspx page

How can I pass the AccountID into the AddFunds.aspx page which will be used to insert details into Funds table which has the AccountID.

I don't want the AccountID to be visible on the AddFunds.aspx page.

Comment: You're supposed to upvote answers that are helpful to you. You should also mark anyone as the answer if they help you as much as you bargained for.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

there are multiple ways to achieve this. i can explain you in brief about the 4 types which we use in our daily programming life cycle.

Please go through the below points.

**1 Query String.**

**FirstForm.aspx.cs**

```
Response.Redirect(“SecondForm.aspx?Parameter=” + TextBox1.Text);
```

**SecondForm.aspx.cs**

```
TextBox1.Text = Request. QueryString["Parameter"].ToString();
```

This is the most reliable way when you are passing integer kind of value or other short parameters.More advance in this method if you are using any special characters in the value while passing it through query string, you must encode the value before passing it to next page. So our code snippet of will be something like this:

**FirstForm.aspx.cs**

```
Response.Redirect(“SecondForm.aspx?Parameter=” + Server.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text));
```

**SecondForm.aspx.cs**

```
TextBox1.Text = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Parameter"].ToString());
```

**2. Passing value through context object**

Passing value through context object is another widely used method.

**FirstForm.aspx.cs**

```
TextBox1.Text = this.Context.Items["Parameter"].ToString();
```

**SecondForm.aspx.cs**

```
this.Context.Items["Parameter"] = TextBox1.Text;
Server.Transfer(“SecondForm.aspx”, true);
```

Note that we are navigating to another page using Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect.Some of us also use Session object to pass values. In that method, value is store in Session object and then later pulled out from Session object in Second page.

**3. Posting form to another page instead of PostBack**

Third method of passing value by posting page to another form. Here is the example of that:

**FirstForm.aspx.cs**

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
buttonSubmit.Attributes.Add(“onclick”, “return PostPage();”);
}
```

And we create a javascript function to post the form.

**SecondForm.aspx.cs**

```
function PostPage()
{
document.Form1.action = “SecondForm.aspx”;
document.Form1.method = “POST”;
document.Form1.submit();
}
TextBox1.Text = Request.Form["TextBox1"].ToString();
```

Here we are posting the form to another page instead of itself. You might get viewstate invalid or error in second page using this method. To handle this error is to put `EnableViewStateMac=false`

**4. Another method is by adding PostBackURL property of control for cross page post back**

In ASP.NET 2.0, Microsoft has solved this problem by adding PostBackURL property of control for cross page post back. Implementation is a matter of setting one property of control and you are done.

**FirstForm.aspx.cs**

```
<asp:Button id=buttonPassValue style=”Z-INDEX: 102″ runat=”server” Text=”Button”         PostBackUrl=”~/SecondForm.aspx”></asp:Button>
```

**SecondForm.aspx.cs**

```
TextBox1.Text = Request.Form["TextBox1"].ToString();
```

In above example, we are assigning PostBackUrl property of the button we can determine the page to which it will post instead of itself. In next page, we can access all controls of the previous page using Request object.

You can also use PreviousPage class to access controls of previous page instead of using classic Request object.

**SecondForm.aspx**

```
TextBox textBoxTemp = (TextBox) PreviousPage.FindControl(“TextBox1″);
TextBox1.Text = textBoxTemp.Text;
```

As you have noticed, this is also a simple and clean implementation of passing value between pages.

Reference: "[How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)"

Answer (score 1):

You need to store it in a session variable:

```
int AccountIdVar;
Session["AccountID"] = AccountIdVar;
```

then you can retrieve later by

```
int AccountIdVar = (int)Session["AccountID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the session variable you stored in the previous page as it should still be accessible or another way is to pass the id over via a querystring such as www.foofoofoo.com?Id=23456.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, you can use Session or Querystring values. You can also just [POST to the new page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178140.aspx)

The [How To Pass Values Between Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx) page is worth looking at too.

Answer (score 0):

The `MSDN` article about [Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx) is the best place to look for.

Answer (score 0):

For this we can also  use  Global variable, create a  module class in that declare all variables with public data type, then assign the values. Once the value is assigned it can be accessed from anywhere.