# Getting TextBox value from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net pass a value into next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241470/asp-net-pass-a-value-into-next-page)

I am requesting quantity from user using text box and after doing calculations with it, I want to display the result on a label on another page.

Here is the code for confirm.aspx.cs

```
public partial class confirm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["user"] != null)
        {
            Label2.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["user"]["userName"]);
            Label3.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["user"]["email"]);
            Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["user"]["items"]);

        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Add("TextBox1Value", TextBox1.Text);
        Response.Redirect("total.aspx");

    }
}
```

and here is the code for another page, total.aspx.cs

```
public partial class total : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int totalprice;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["confirm"]["quantity"]);
        int quantity = Session["TextBox1Value"];

        if (Request.Cookies["user"]["items"] == "Tyres")
        {
            totalprice = 20 * quantity;

            Label2.Text = totalprice.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Anywhere I am may be wrong or any suggestions on how can I do it?

Comment: The `.Text` property already encodes.  You should not double-encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast it to `integer` type to do your calculations.

```
 if(Session["TextBox1Value"]!=null)
 {
   string strQuantity = Session["TextBox1Value"].ToString();
   int quantity=Convert.ToInt32(strQuantity);
   //now you can use quantity to do all your calculations
 }
```

Comment: I am getting an error on string strQuantity = Session["TextBox1Value"];

Comment: You should have posted the error. Try Session["TextBox1Value"].ToString()

Comment: @AnkurKaushal: Woh ! I missed a `.ToString()` call. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to pass the values from one page to another..

One of my answer on the same topic will help you get the details.

Please refer [pass a value into next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241470/asp-net-pass-a-value-into-next-page/8241577)