# How to pass value to new window in ASP.NET on button click

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET to open a new window on clicking a button. Here in `MainPage.aspx` i will enter a value in `TextBox` and press the button. This value should be obtained and displayed in the new window that opens. Im opening the new window using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`. But im not sure how to pass the value and display it in new page. Im using the following code for this,

**MainPage.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Styles/Main.css'/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form_main" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_value" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn_open" Text="Open" runat="server" OnClick="btn_open_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**MainPage.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btn_open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value = txt_value.Text;
    // Pass value to new page when opening it
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( 'NewPage.aspx', null, 'height=700,width=760,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);
}
```

**NewPage.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>New Page</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Styles/New.css'/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form_new" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_received" runat="server" Text="" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**NewPage.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_received.Text = "Value got from MainPage.aspx";
}
```

Comment: you can use cookies/session to pass values from one form to another.

Comment: Many options you got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241470/pass-a-value-into-next-page

Comment: Ok but which method i should use when using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` and how to combine that code with this?